# Uso del verbo superar para indicar en mayor cantidad

Tags: uso-de-palabras

¿Se puede usar el verbo **superar** para indicar que algo se encuentra en mayor cantidad en relación con otra cosa, o que sucede un mayor número de veces, como en las siguientes oraciones?

> Lo único que busco son momentos de felicidad que **superen** a los de
> tristeza.
>
> Las risas que solté **superan** con creces las lágrimas que derramé.

Yo mismo creé las oraciones anteriores, así que no estoy seguro de si son correctas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El DLE dice de [superar](https://dle.rae.es/superar):

> 3. tr. **rebasar** (‖ exceder de un límite). *La temperatura del desierto supera los 50 grados.* U. t. c. prnl.

Esto no deja claro si se puede usar el verbo *superar* para comparar dos cosas cualesquiera (¿qué se considera exactamente un *límite*?), pero el DPD en su entrada para *exceder* dice:

> **exceder(se).** 1. Cuando significa, dicho de una persona o cosa, ‘superar [a otra]’, es transitivo y el complemento directo, aun siendo de cosa, va precedido de *a* (→ [a<sup>2</sup>, 1.1l](https://www.rae.es/dpd/exceder?id=ctMgM8Bp2D6ELPuNfg#11l)): «*El ingreso excede al gasto*» (*Excélsior* [Méx.] 21.10.96).

Es decir, parece que el DPD acepta el uso de *superar* como "ser más grande/numeroso que" (ejemplo: "el ingreso supera el gasto"). En mi experiencia (España), este uso es común, y las dos oraciones propuestas en la pregunta son correctas.